# Need to hide my URL in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications

I want to hide my actual URL from some other arbitrary URL which is to be taken from .properties file.
For eg:- `https://localhost:8080/<WebApplicationContext>/login.xhtml`
In above if i have mapping of login.xhtml to dummy.st then URl should be
`https://localhost:8080/<WebApplicationContext>/dummy.st`

For all the pages in my application it should be like that.

Please suggest how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 6):

See if [Pretty Faces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) will let you do what you need. IT seems that you can do it with

```
<url-mapping id="login">
    <pattern value="/dummy.st" />
    <view-id value="/login.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

However I've never used Pretty Faces. It's an example from documentation.